# How to make a generic MethodInvoke?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Context
 I want to make this call via reflection

`instanceOfEventPublisher.Publish<T>(T eventInst);`

When I call

`
private void GenCall(IEventPublisher eventPublisher, object theEventObj){

```
        var thePublisher = eventPublisher.GetType();
        thePublisher.InvokeMember(
            "Publish",
            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null,
            eventPublisher,
            new object[] {theEventObj}
            );
    }
```

`

I get:
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'EventAggregator.EventPublisher.Publish' not found.

How to call the generic ?

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer if you indicated the programming language. Is that VB.Net?

Comment: Is the Publish method generic, or is IEventPublisher generic and the Publish method is taking IEventPublisher's type argument as a parameter?

Comment: If IEventPublisher was generic wouldn't that need to be expressed in the GenCall method definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to do `GetMethods()` and search for the "Publish" `MethodInfo`.  Or if "Publish" isn't overloaded you might get away with just `GetMethod("Publish")`.  In either case, you'll need to call `MakeGenericMethod()` on the `MethodInfo` to add your type arguments.

```
MethodInfo constructedPublish = thePublisher.GetMethod("Publish")
    .MakeGenericMethod( theEventObject.GetType() );
constructedPublish.Invoke( eventPublisher, new object[] { theEventObject } );
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the MakeGenericType method like such:

```
var realizedType = thePublisher.MakeGenericType(eventObj.GetType());
```

Then you can call the Publish method as you have it on the realizedType. This is true if your dealing with a Generic type; however, your code doesn't look like it is. The interface you have coming in for the eventPublisher is not a generic interface.

Can you post the rest of your code, so we can see the interface defnition and the generic class definitions.

**Edit**

Here's some sample code I whipped up showing how to call a method on a generic type through reflection:

```
  public class Publisher<T>
    {
        public void Publish(T args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var type = typeof(Publisher<>);

        Publisher<EventArgs> publisher = new Publisher<EventArgs>();

        var realizedType = type.MakeGenericType(typeof(EventArgs));
        realizedType.InvokeMember("Publish", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
        null,
        publisher
        ,
        new object[] { new EventArgs() });

    }
```

Comment: I've revised the formatting swallowed <T> it has to be
instanceOfEventPublisher.Publish<T>(T eventInst);

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you use the backtick notation:

```
Publish`1[[assemblyQualifiedNameOfTypeOfClassl]]
```

(Just a guess; not tested).